# How to use v-show with dynamic element in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a dynamic table rendering where columns and rows of the table are rendered dynamically.

So here I have two sibling `<td>` elements in each row:

```vue
<td :key="`td3-${index}`" :id="`show_${key}`" v-show="`show_${key}`">
  <input type="text" :v-model="key" :name="key" :value="entry[key]" />
</td>
<td :key="`td4-${index}`">
  <a href="#" @click="showField(key)">Edit</a>
</td>
```

In the `onclick` event of the link in the second `<td>` I have to show and hide the first `<td>` element. Since it's dynamic I will have multiple rows. So I declared a dynamic boolean in my data to show and hide the specific `<td>` based on the click of another `<td>` in the same row.

`` v-show="`show_${key}`" `` - this is show property with dynamic key

```
  show_firstname: false,
  show_lastname: false,
  show_email: false,
  show_orgname: false
```

I created separate boolean elements for every `<td>` in each row.

[image: Table structure]

But whenever I change the value of `v-show` property with the on click of second `<td>` element it's not making any difference. So I could not show or hide the `<td>`. Maybe `v-show` takes `` "`show_${key}`" `` as a string value not replacing true or false correctly. Can someone help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try organising the show_ in an object instead of a flat list of properties?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-csncc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark